# Auto-Fill ajax response on dynamic fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using auto-fill with a ajax request, which is working fine for static fields.
for example:

```
$this->registerJs("$(document).delegate('.form-control','change',function(event){

    $.ajax({
        url: '".yii\helpers\Url::toRoute("ot-note/instrument1")."',
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {id: $(this).val(),
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('#otinstrumententry-0-instrument_code').val(data.instrument_code);

            },

         beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            alert('loading!');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('An error occured!');
            alert('Error in ajax request');
        }
    });
});");
```

My fields are added dynamically and it is not working for the dynamically added fields, the code is like this:
the `id` of the fields are becoming like
`#field-0-instrument_code`
`#field-1-instrument_cdoe`

Except for the first field, the successive fields are not recognized by Jquery, which are added dynamically.

How I can resolve this problem.
thanks.

**addition** code for dynamic fields

```
<div id="instrument_entry">
    <h3>Instruments Used</h3>
    <?php $id = 0; ?>

    <?php foreach ($otinstrumentModels as $otinstrument) { ?>      

        <div id="language" class="work-data-pad brdr-work marbtm10 row">
            <div class="col-md-4">     
            <?= $form->field($otinstrument, '[' . $id . ']' . 'instrument_name')->DropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\Instrument::find()->all(), 'id', 'instrument_name' ),
[ 'prompt' => 'Please Select' ])?>    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">     
            <?= $form->field($otinstrument, '[' . $id . ']' . 'instrument_code')->textInput(['maxlength' => 255,'class'=>'form-control']) ?>      
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">     
            <?= $form->field($otinstrument, '[' . $id . ']' . 'hrs_time')->textInput(['maxlength' => 255])->label('Hrs-Time') ?>      
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">     
            <?= $form->field($otinstrument, '[' . $id . ']' . 'total_charges')->textInput(['maxlength' => 255]) ?>      
            </div>
            <?php ?>
    <div style="margin-top: 30px;" class="col-md-3 <?php echo ($id < 1) ? 'dnone' : 'dblock'; ?>" id="divDelete" class="row-fluid">           
    <a class="ft11 btn-remove" onclick="deleteSection(this, 'instrument_entry');"><span class="marleft18">Remove</span></a>               
    </div>  
</div>
    <?php $id++; ?> 
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

**Generated HTML**

```
<div id="instrument_entry">
    <h3>Instruments Used</h3>



        <div id="language" class="work-data-pad brdr-work marbtm10 row">
            <div class="col-md-4">     
            <div class="form-group field-otinstrumententry-0-instrument_name">
<label class="control-label" for="otinstrumententry-0-instrument_name">Instrument Name</label>
<select id="otinstrumententry-0-instrument_name" class="form-control" name="OtInstrumentEntry[0][instrument_name]">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="1">IMPLANTS(ORTHOPEDIC)</option>
<option value="2">O2 CHARGES PER HOUR</option>
</select>

<div class="help-block"></div>
</div>    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">     
            <div class="form-group field-otinstrumententry-0-instrument_code">
<label class="control-label" for="otinstrumententry-0-instrument_code">Instrument Code</label>
<input type="text" id="otinstrumententry-0-instrument_code" class="form-control" name="OtInstrumentEntry[0][instrument_code]" maxlength="255">

<div class="help-block"></div>
</div>      
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">     
            <div class="form-group field-otinstrumententry-0-hrs_time">
<label class="control-label" for="otinstrumententry-0-hrs_time">Hrs-Time</label>
<input type="text" id="otinstrumententry-0-hrs_time" class="form-control" name="OtInstrumentEntry[0][hrs_time]" maxlength="255">

<div class="help-block"></div>
</div>      
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">     
            <div class="form-group field-otinstrumententry-0-total_charges">
<label class="control-label" for="otinstrumententry-0-total_charges">Total Charges</label>
<input type="text" id="otinstrumententry-0-total_charges" class="form-control" name="OtInstrumentEntry[0][total_charges]" maxlength="255">

<div class="help-block"></div>
</div>      
            </div>
                <div style="margin-top: 30px;" class="col-md-3 dnone" id="divDelete" class="row-fluid">           
    <a class="ft11 btn-remove" onclick="deleteSection(this, 'instrument_entry');"><span class="marleft18">Remove</span></a>               
    </div>  
</div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary sec-btn marbtm10" onclick="addNewSection('instrument_entry', 'OtInstrumentEntry')">+ Add Instrument</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>        </div>
    </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: I think, you should add a PHP tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

First, You can try this:

```
$this->registerJs("$(document).delegate('.form-control','change',function(event){
   sendAjax(this);
});");

function sendAjax(element)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: '".yii\helpers\Url::toRoute("ot-note/instrument1")."',
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {id: $(element).val()},
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('#otinstrumententry-0-instrument_code').val(data.instrument_code);

            },

         beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            alert('loading!');
         },
         error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('An error occured!');
            alert('Error in ajax request');
        }
    });
}
```

Now you can add `onchange="sendAjax(this)"` inside newly added element. I think this solution can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's only one hardcoded value in your code (in the `success` handler), so I'll assume that's where the problem is coming from. You could use `.attr("id")` to get the current field id, use a regex to get the number and use that to generate the selector:

```
    var currentId = $(this).attr("id");
    var generatedId = "";
    if ( currentId.match(/otinstrumententry-\d+-/) ) {
        generatedId = "#" + currentId.match(/otinstrumententry-\d+-/)[0]
                          + "instrument_code";
    }
    $.ajax({
        // ...
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if ( generatedId !== "" ) {
                $( generatedId ).val(data.instrument_code);
            }
        }
    });
```

Also, it's worth noting *exactly* which elements you want to invoke this hander on. From the look of it it looks like it's just the `select`s, but I'm not entire sure without knowing the business logic:

```
$(document).delegate('select.form-control','change',function(event){
});
```

On a side note, if you're using jQuery 1.7 or newer, you should replace `.delegate` with its newer incarnation `.on`. If you're using an older version, you should consider updating it

Comment: Hi bigt - I have tried your suggestion, ajax call is firing correctly, but instead of filling the data in the `instrument_code` field, the `drop-down` selection field is going white.

Comment: Ok I have further update the question I think this is what you need.

Comment: @Joshi Check the last edit, see if it helps to point you in the right direction.

Comment: I am getting this error = `SyntaxError: expected expression, got ','
 

},`

Comment: I can't help you with syntax errors I'm afraid. I do however **strongly recommend** that you understand what the above answer does and use it as a guide to identify the problem and find your own solution rather than copy it directly

Comment: Hi BIgt - Thanks for your help, I will sure fiddle with it.

Comment: Hi blgt - I think I have got rid of the syntax error - but still I am getting the data field in the first field only, successive fields I am getting the response, but the fields are not filled, it is remaining blank. any other suggestion?